# Adding rows to table with different number of columns and formatting table in a pdf using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pdf

Adding rows/columns to existing table and formatting tables in a pdf using python

I need help adding a row, and format my pdf and I am stuck.
Here is what I am trying to do. First I need to parse through a single excel sheet where there are multiple rows corresponding to different facilities. Those need to be split into separate excel sheets (done this) and then made into a pdf. In the pdf I need to make multiple tables, each table has different information from those excel sheets. Since there are some names in the files that are of different number of characters, the table should automatically adjust column widths, which I have done.
I was successful making most of the first table, however I am running into the error where the list index is out of range when I add the last two rows because they don't have the same number of columns. I also need to add an empty row on top. Furthermore, I was trying to add boarders throughout the whole table.

For adding the rows and columns, I tried add.row() to the table, but that was unsuccessful. For adding boarders everywhere on the table, I tried using a for loop but the pdfs ended up squishing all the information in what looked like one column.

Here is the code I have so far

```
#read excel file
input_file_path = "path.xlsx"
df = pandas.read_excel(input_file_path)

output_directory = os.path.dirname(input_file_path)
output_file_name = "split.xlsx"
output_file_path = os.path.join(output_directory, output_file_name)

writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(output_file_path, engine = "xlsxwriter",  options={'strings_to_formulas': False})

\#iterate throught the rows of the excel sheet and split them according to their rows and name them according to the start of the row
for index, row in df.iterrows():
sheet_name = str(row[4])
row.to_frame().transpose().to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheet_name, index = False)

writer.save()

excel_file = pandas.ExcelFile("path/split.xlsx")

\#iterate through each sheet
for sheet_name in excel_file.sheet_names:
\#load sheet into dataframe
df_parse = excel_file.parse(sheet_name)

    story = []
    # Add the title and embargo information
    title = '<b>Long-Term and Assisted Living Directory</b>'
    month_year = 'Month Year'  # Replace with the actual month and year
    embargo = '<font color="red">(EMBARGOED)</font>'
    title_paragraph = Paragraph(f"{title}<br/>{month_year} [{embargo}]", getSampleStyleSheet()['Heading1'])
    story.append(title_paragraph)
    
    table_data = [
        ["Facility", df_parse.at[0,"FACILITY_NM"], "Service Type", "Long Term"],
        ["Health Authority", df_parse.at[0, "HA_NM"], "Regulation/Legislation", df_parse.at[0,"REGULATION"]], 
        ["Street Adress", df_parse.at[0, "STREET_ADDRESS"], "Accreditation status", df_parse.at[0, "ACCRED_STATUS"]],
        ["City/postal code", f"{df_parse.at[0, 'CITY']}/{df_parse.at[0, 'POSTAL_CODE']}", "Accreditation expiry date", df_parse.at[0,"ACCRED_EXPIRY"]],
        ["Phone Number", df_parse.at[0,"PHONE"], "Contact for complaints", df_parse.at[0,"COMPLAINT_CONTACT"]],
        ["Operator (type)", f"{df_parse.at[0, 'OWNERSHIP_TYPE_CD']}({df_parse.at[0, 'OWNERSHIP_TYPE']})", "Phone number of complaint contact", df_parse.at[0, "COMPLAINT_PHONE"]],
        ["Opened", df_parse.at[0, "OPEN_DATE"], "Personal spending account", df_parse.at[0, "SPENDING_ACCOUNT"]],
        ["Counsils", df_parse.at[0,"COUNCILS"], "Visitor parking(cost)", df_parse.at[0, "PARKING_COSTS"]],
        ["Meetings held", df_parse.at[0, "MEETINGS_HELD"], "Average Wait Time", df_parse.at[0, "AVG_WAIT_TIME"]]
        ]
    
    
        
    column_widths = []
    for column in range(len(table_data[0])):
        column_width = max([len(str(row[column])) for row in table_data]) *0.05
        column_widths.append(column_width)
    
            
    table = Table(table_data, colWidths = column_widths)
    
    
    
    #create pdf file, save to desired directory. Can be modified
    pdf_file = f"path/PDFs/{sheet_name}.pdf"
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdf_file, pagesize = letter)
    
    doc.build([table])
```